# Birth certificate problem for passport - two different locations?

Tags: passports, paperwork

There is difference in name of birthplace in leaving certificate and  birth certificate .Is any problem will occur in issuing passport?

In birth certificate-  birthplace- vijapur
In leaving cerificate-  Jantral, ta- vijapu

Answer (score 2):

You need to fill in the very simple [List of Documents Required for Fresh Passport Issuance](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/docAdvisor/attachmentAdvFresh) form and check in the results whether the leaving certificate is there. I am reasonable sure it is not. You need the birth certificate and current address proofs.